# Does webgl depend on the OpenGL in the OS?

Tags: macos, opengl, webgl, compatibility

Mac OS does not support OpenGL anymore after MacOS 10.14 Mojave. Will the change influence the compatibility of Webgl?

Comment: MacOS supports OpenGL after Mojave, it's just deprecated. They will not be updating it anymore. They are not removing it.

Answer (score 1):

> Does webgl depend on the OpenGL in the OS?

Not necessarily.  For instance on Windows Firefox and Chrome use [ANGLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANGLE_(software)) (defaulting to its Direct3D backend) to provide hardware-accelerated WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

Per this post from [the Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/314676#314676):

> "Apple's announcement that it is deprecating OpenGL doesn't have any impact for WebGL development using Safari. The underlying technologies might change in the future, but WebGL won't change."